# unknown variable 'file-key-management-filename'

Tags: transparent-data-encryption, mariadb-10.3, debian

New installation of Debian 10, with MariaDB 10.3.29. Trying to set up encryption-at-rest, but MariaDB won't start due to an error...

```
[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'file-key-management-filename=/etc/openssl/keys/keyfile.key'
```

My server.cnf has...

```
[mariadb-10.3]
plugin-load-add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/openssl/keys/keyfile.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
```

The above config I have working in a Centos7 system, so I'm baffled as to why it isn't working on Debian10. This message is what I encountered when trying to install encryption in a MariaDB pre-10.1 version that didn't have encryption as an option, but I know encryption is an option after Mariadb 10.1, so it should be available in this package (unexciting installation via apt), right?
I have tried moving the cnf code around, to the [mysqld] and [mariadb] sections to no avail. There are no previous versions of MariaDB hanging around - this is a clean install.

Has anyone encountered this issue and solved it already?

Comment: you can check in the manual since when a feature exists

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by installing MariaDB 10.4. Not sure why 10.3 wasn't working, but I checked another debian10 system running 10.3 and it was the same issue there too. MariaDB 10.4 seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is just a matter of load order, in that case adding a `loose_` prefix in front of the plugin specific variables helps, e.g.:

```
[mariadb-10.3]
plugin-load-add = file_key_management
loose-file_key_management_filename = /etc/openssl/keys/keyfile.key
loose-file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
```